# react work with other js function written using jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am writing a web application which use react and can use scanner to read barcode. the scanner detect and read function was written using jquery. So my question is how can I pass the scanned string to react component ?
The scanning part is just javascript code which use jquery to get scanned string. the react component will display scanned string and other info from server. I am wondering how react component can get the scanned string.

thanks

Comment: please post your code

Comment: sorry Miguel, don't have this part of code yet.

Comment: Is the react component in the same project as the jquery code?

Comment: hi d-reaper,  I need the scannner js lib to get scanned string.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use global var, which is:

```
window.myBarcode = {barCodeData: yourBarcodeLibReturns, moreControlFlags:{}};
```

Then, use it inside a component. Remember to use some control flags to tag update time and avoid conflict between components.

Comment: Hi Jack,  thanks . Sorry I am quite new to react and js . Do you mean when I got a scanned string, then set it to the global var ? then how to detect it changed and use it by react component ? Could you give me more detail or a sample?  Really appreciate your answer.